# NiDAQMX close all created tasks

Tags: python, labview, nidaqmx

I would like to close all the previously created tasks in the `nidaqmx-python` module.

How can I do this?

In example, I have a number of previously opened tasks:

```
for i in range(10):
    nidaqmx.Task()
```

which I did not close. However, I want to close them now.

Comment: You probably want to save the return values of `.Task()` and then later call a method on that returned object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a [reset_device()](https://github.com/ni/nidaqmx-python/blob/db9cf5b3b5a12393548e2a619dbdbb265e5fb473/nidaqmx/system/device.py#L2201) on the device you are using? It should make all tasks associated with the device able to be started again.

edit: though it cleared the tasks, but it only aborts them.

Comment: Just a remark: this is a last resort! You should keep a list of open tasks and close them, or use the structure `with nidaqmx.Task() as task:` to let the code handle open and close tasks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the source, you'll have to do something like the following:

```
tasks = []
for i in range(10):
    tasks.append(nidaqmx.Task())

# Some code ...

for task in tasks:
    task.close()
```

See https://github.com/ni/nidaqmx-python/blob/master/nidaqmx/task.py#L448

Comment: I do not have the tasks saved in a list. Lets say the program crashed between measurements.

Comment: Are the task names fixed? IE could you attempt to clear the task on EXE start and handle the error?